# OpenBSD X, mouse only scrolls down

Tags: xorg, x11, openbsd

I just got a new OpenBSD 4.8 instance up and running with Xfce. The only issue I'm having is that the mouse wheel only ever scrolls down. When I physically scroll up, X scrolls down. When I do scroll up X seems to page down, as it scrolls much more area than when I scroll down.

Comment: Run `xev` and use the wheel in its window. What events do you see? (Expected: `ButtonPress` and `ButtonRelease` for button 4 going up, button 5 going down)

Comment: hrm... I'm getting button 5 for both up and down. Same exact mouse on FreeBSD and I get 4&5 (scrolls fine).  Thanks for reference to 'xev' :)

Comment: There's an Xorg.conf option "ZAxisMapping" that should be responsible for that. Maybe you need to change it? Also, which X driver is reponsible for the mouse, some direct one (PS/2, USB) or via some daemon (eg. moused)?

Comment: @Patrick if xev shows both buttons showing the same event, I don't think ZAxisMapping will have any effect. @Justin Is this a USB or PS/2 mouse?  And does it have more than the usual set of buttons?

Comment: It's a usb mouse, and I'm ashamed to say that it's a Microsoft Wheel Mouse (Just what I ended up with)

Comment: As I understand it, ZAxisMapping happens in the driver, so xev sees the data after ZAxisMapping did its work.